# How to get Image of Parent product for grouped child product in a template?

Tags: magento2, product-images, quote, grouped-products

```
<td><img src="<?=$this->getImageUrl($item->getProduct(), 'image', 300) ?>" style="max-width: 15rem"/></td>
<td valign="top">
  <p><a href="<?=$item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo "Quantity : ".$item->getQty()?><br/><?php echo $item->getName() ?></a></p>
  <b><?=$this->formatPrice($item->getPrice()) ?></b>
</td>
```

from the quote model.